# How to extract an image patch from an image using its SIFT data?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave, sift

Using a SIFT generator, I can generate a 128-dimension SIFT descriptors for an image with the following data for each vector:

- Center of the interest region
- Its scale and orientation
- matrix A that defines the elliptic support of the region

My question is how, in Matlab/Octave, can I extract an elliptic image patch of an interest region from the original image using only its SIFT data, i.e. its center of the interest region and the matrix A?

I know that I can get an elliptic patch of an image `I` knowing the ellipse function:

```
[n_row n_col n_cha] = size(I);
[xx, yy] = ndgrid((1:n_row)-y,(1:n_col)-x);
mask = uint8((xx.^2/9 + yy.^2/4) < 100^2); % ellipse function
C = uint8(zeros(n_row, n_col));
C = I.*mask;
```

However, I don't know how you can get an ellipse function with only the SIFT data. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify: What information does SIFT provide? How are eliptic regions related to SIFT?